# Programmatically create a MaterialButton with Outline style

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-button, androidx

I would programmatically like to create a button as defined in the design guidelines here: https://material.io/design/components/buttons.html#outlined-button, looking like this:

[image]

In XML I'm able to do this, using this piece of layout xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/buttonGetStarted"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
    android:text="@string/title_short_intro" />
```

What I'm looking for is an example that shows how to do this using Java code? I have tried the following:

```
MaterialButton testSignIn = new MaterialButton( new ContextThemeWrapper( this, R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_Button_OutlinedButton));
String buttonText = "Sign-in & empty test account";
testSignIn.setText( buttonText );
```

But this does not result in the outline variant:

[image]

Comment: If I'm not wrong, it's : `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored` See if that is answers your question.

Comment: Just tested this (changed the R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_Button_OutlinedButton in my code to R.style.Widget_AppCompat_Button_Borderless_Colored). This makes no difference.

Comment: Add both `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored` to xml and the same in java-kotlin then try.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @masterwork, no... Still using an XML based layout as a work around (please keep me updated in case you find a solution).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use below:

```
MaterialButton testSignIn = new MaterialButton(context, null, R.attr.borderlessButtonStyle);
String buttonText = "Sign-in & empty test account";
testSignIn.setText(buttonText);
```

Comment: `R.attr.borderlessButtonStyle` does not create **Outlined Button**.  I think the correct attribute would be `R.attr.materialButtonOutlinedStyle`

Comment: Thanks, I was using the plain class `Button` as they claim that they transform them, but I does not transform them magically when it is done by code, only from xml.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to apply a *Outlined* button you can use the **`R.attr.materialButtonOutlinedStyle`** attribute style in the constructor:

```
MaterialButton outlinedButton = new MaterialButton(context,null, R.attr.materialButtonOutlinedStyle);
outlinedButton.setText("....");
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly, and here for Xamarin.Android: new MaterialButton(Context, null, Resource.Attribute.materialButtonOutlinedStyle);

Answer (score 0):

`MaterialButton` has `strokeColor` and `strokeWidth` which is used to set the outline.

```
val _strokeColor = getColorStateList(R.styleable.xxx_strokeColor)
val _strokeWidth = getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.xxx_strokeWidth, 0)

button = MaterialButton(context).apply {
    layoutParams = LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_PARENT)
    strokeColor = _strokeColor
    strokeWidth = _strokeWidth
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create outlined button layout outlined_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton>
```

Then inflate outlined button in runtime

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
MaterialButton button = (MaterialButton)inflater.inflate(R.layout.outlined_button, vg, false);
```

Comment: This worked for me. Kotlin code to inflate: val b: MaterialButton = this.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.outline_button, null) as MaterialButton